# subscription and normal product checkout at the same time by using laravel and stripe

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I have created separately to pay for normal product (I have used a cart) and pay for a subscription.

But now I need to add the subscription to the cart and checkout it at the same time with other products in the cart

Is it possible to do using strip ?

Any help is deeply appropriated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in the stripe.  you need to create a customer on stripe using card details of the customer.

You can then create a separate charge using customer for products which are not recurring. and another method call which will create a subscription for recurring products. many websites do this which offer recurring products in the cart.

Create a customer using stripe token retrieved from stripe.js

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

\Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "description" => "Customer for elizabeth.taylor@example.com",
  "source" => "tok_mastercard" // obtained with Stripe.js
));
```

Then you to create charge for all nonrecurring items in your payment collection service

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 2000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => "customer_id", // obtained with previous request
  "description" => "Charge for aubrey.white@example.com"
));
```

After creating customer you can create a subscription for that customer for all recurring item. this need to be done in two steps if your amount is dynamic

1. Add a plan for that amount in your account stripe supports unlimited plan in account
2. Create a subscription to the customer for the plan created in the previous step.

code to create a plan

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

\Stripe\Plan::create(array(
  "amount" => 5000,
  "interval" => "month",
  "name" => "Emerald small",
  "currency" => "usd",
  "id" => "emerald-small"
));
```

code to create a subscription

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

\Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
  "customer" => "customer_id",
  "items" => array(
    array(
      "plan" => "plan_id_created",
    ),
  )
));
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: how are you generating stripe token? using Stripe.js right?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include code snippet. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I’d create the subscription, but also add the additional products as line items to the first invoice.